# Apache Camel select then insert

Tags: sql, database, apache-camel

I am very very new to Apache Camel and I am looking to create a simple application which reads 200 products from mysql db 1 and then inserts the products into mysql db 2. No changes required to the data, it is just a one for one bulk select and then bulk insert.

I have been looking at the camel-sql-example project which uses the sql component. I like the way it's structured so I've attempted to go with this example project as my base.

Would anyone be able to help me with the location of a good example for this or giving me a rough indication of what my camel route (spring arcehtype) should look like?

Is something like this correct?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="sourceDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    ...
  </bean> 

  <bean id="targetDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    ...
  </bean>     

  <!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
  <bean id="sourceSql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="sourceDataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="targetSql" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="targetDataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="productBean" class="org.apache.camel.example.sql.ProductBean"/>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder location="classpath:sql.properties" id="placeholder"/>

    <route id="processProduct-route">
        <from uri="sourceSql:{{sql.selectProduct}}"/>
        <to uri="targetSql:{{sql.insertProduct}}"/>
        <log message="${body}"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this today and what I've specified above seems to work! Something that I did not expect though was that the route just loops and continues to run multiple times. I only need it to run once. I'm looking into how to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544639/apache-camel-sql-component-how-to-execute-only-once?rq=1